# can we use wasPreUpgrade and WASPostUpgrade scripts to migrate from one machine to another which runs same Websphere version v8.5.5.17

Tags: migration, websphere, was

Trying to move the Dmgrs and Nodes to new machines with different OS.
The WAS install paths and profile locations are different on source and target servers

Both source and target machines are on 8.5.5.17 versions
Different OS for source (intel) &  target (power)

I wanted to check if we can use wasPreUpgrade and WASPostUpgrade scripts for this kind of migration too and follow the steps listed on this
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was-zos/8.5.5?topic=SS7K4U_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.migration.nd.doc/ae/tmig_migrate_remote_commandline.html

OR

can we use the approach to be able to use different install locations

do a new install, create new profiles and then use

importWASConfig.py script and exportWASConfig.py script from old envt to new envt

Answer (score 0):

No, those scripts require you to upgrade to a newer major version of WebSphere.

Someone has figured out a procedure to move profiles over, maybe this achieves what you need to do: http://akhilesh-humbe.blogspot.com/2013/06/moving-profile-to-new-host-in-websphere.html

Otherwise you will have to request support from the vendor to help you figure out how to move the profiles.

Comment: but can I have different WAS install location though.. on new server i have different install paths

Comment: or can we use the approach to be able to use different install locations 

do a new install, create new profiles and then use 

importWASConfig.py script and exportWASConfig.py script from old envt to new envt